# Everything has disappeared apart from the mouse pointer and desktop background

Tags: 12.10, gnome-terminal, gnome-panel

I had just entered these commands in the terminal:sudo service

```
sudo service lightdm stop 
sudo apt-get install mesa- utils 
sudo service lightdm start
```

Then a black screen came on with battery check [ok] on it. Nothing happened for so long I assumed it  had crashed and so I turned my netbook off. 
When I turned  it on again I was given a slightly different login screen, when I logged in everything was gone. Pressing the super key does nothing but I am able to get a terminal up with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

No idea what I have done here or how to fix it! Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: after typing <kbd>unity &</kbd>  in the terminal this was shown 
[terminal] (https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BFJAYDqCIAAVWiW.jpg) 
Don

Comment: Try running `unity &` in terminal, to restart unity.

Comment: It did not work, its saying compiz (core) - error plug in init failed: unity she'll. And goes on to say extension "glx" missing,  I'll upload a pic of the full text to my twitter @optimussime

Comment: Please update the question with any further information.

Comment: I can't do that I'm afraid I don't know any more O_o

Comment: I mean, full output from `unity &` and/or the picture of the text.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to post Images and I can't use a browser on my netbook atm I'm doing this on my mob so it's not gonna practical to type out the full output sorry to be a pain a link is the best I can do right now @Frederik Spang

Comment: Are you using nVidia graphics by any chance?

Comment: If I'm honest I did mistakenly download nvidia drivers before I realised my netbook only had on board graphics.

Comment: Thinking about a reinstall (for the third time) because either nobody knows how to fix this or they have not deemed me worthy of their knowledge. Nice guys nice

Answer (score 0):

I think You should first try to repair unity or anyother desktop environment you have (like gnome or KDE).
If you are using unity then first open the terminal by pressing ctrl-alt-t
and then  type 
unity-reset
this may reset the unity desktop environment.
IF the problem persist the uninstall unity by typing (in this press enter after each line)(this process requires internet)

```
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get remove compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get purge compiz
```

and then reinstall unity by typing

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

If you are using gnome then reset gnome

And do the same if you are using KDE
(you may search the internet how to reinstall gnome or KDE)

Then restart it